# Send a file to sharepoint using JavaScript application

Tags: javascript, file, save

I am familiar with user interface of SharePoint but I dont know SharePoint from programming point of view. I have a JavaScript application and I need on the button click to send a file from a variable to SharePoint site. Using Fiddler I caught that there is a something like this https://site.domain/_vti_bin/Copy.asmx?op=CopyIntoItems and I think that this could do what I need. But can I somehow specified where to save the file and specified the file?

I would be glad for any help.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should create the JavaScript application which uses [SharePoint's REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142380.aspx). What you are looking for is how to upload a file to SharePoint site using REST API. There's a detailed guide on MSDN about [Upload a file by using the REST API and jQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn769086.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which should get you started.

See also e.g:

- [Upload files to SharePoint Online using REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/123533/upload-files-to-sharepoint-online-using-rest-api)
- [Upload file into sharepoint document library using REST](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/157862/upload-file-into-sharepoint-document-library-using-rest)

Comment: Thank you Moe for your answer. I tried it via REST but I have some issues. I tried to connect to SHP by use: var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl); executor.executeAsync() in my JS code but I need SP.js file. I searched on the internet but I didn't find how or where to find this file. My application will not run on the same pc where SHP is installed so if this file is a part of SHP installation folder how can I import this file into my js code? Thanks for any answer.

Comment: For your question, `sp.js` should be already on your SharePoint's files on `/_layouts/15/sp.js`. See e.g. http://blog.qumsieh.ca/2013/10/30/how-to-properly-reference-sp-js-in-a-master-page/ to get started on referencing it.